# Full-screen fragment to fragment transition displayed main activity during fragment transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

In my android application, I had one main activity(i.e.Home) and two full-screen fragments. I can access theses three using Navigation Drawer. These two fragments act as the separate screen but actually its top on main activity. 
In my case, I clicked the first fragment then I clicked the second fragment. During this time, I closed the first fragment and displayed the second fragment. But, main activity screen was now displayed one second during fragment transition.

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
        if(!item.isChecked())
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        item.setChecked(true);
        if (previousMenuItem != item.getItemId()) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.fragment_two) {
                initialiseFragmentTwo();
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_main_activity) {
                getSupportFragmentManager(). popBackStackImmediate(null, POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
            else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_fragment_one){
                initialiseFragmentOne();
            }
        }
        previousMenuItem = item.getItemId();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer != null) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: I updated my question Mr. egek92

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE** try to use **replace**

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

See here below links

http://chrisrisner.com/Using-Fragments-with-the-Navigation-Drawer-Activity

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/